# WebRtc Video not showing in any browser using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: video, webrtc

Hello i want to show live video of laptop cam in my html. i have implemented using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() but video is not displaying. i have tried in localhost with http and https also same result. i am not getting any error in console. the code i used is

```
<script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var constraints = { audio: false, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
        };
    </script>
    <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="400"></video>
```

[it is showing like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbfrE.png)

Comment: What browser do you use? Any errors in the console? Webcam connected and permission granted?

Comment: i had checked in chrome, firefox. no errors in console, its returning variants also, webcam is connected and permission granted, i can hear audio also but video is not displaying

Comment: Your code works in Codepen. Try to reduce the resolution, maybe your webcam can't handle the 1280*720 and should throw an overconstraint error...

Comment: What OS and camera?